# background color behind bootstrap 2.3 tooltip

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

I have a Joomla website using the built-in Joomla Bootstrap 2.3.2 tooltips. The  problem is that the tooltips pop up with a background color (not the `.tooltip-inner` color, but the tooltip's container) that doesn't match the page color.

Can anyone tell me the property I'd modify to set the color of the main tooltip container?

Comment: try `.tooltip { background-color: your_color ; }`

Comment: @TamilSelvan-- that was the first property I tried, and it made no difference. Thanks!